# Djaty - What is the `djatyReqId` that's being sent with all ajax requests?

Tags: djaty

I have installed Djaty JS SDK normally as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script src="djaty.min.js" djaty-api-key="djaty-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx">
    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

It works now successfully and I start receiving my first test errors.

I just wonder, what is the `djatyReqId` that's being sent with all ajax requests sent from my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Djaty will be able to link the bugs coming from frontend and backend together by sending this `djatyReqId` with every Ajax request.

For example, if an Ajax request causes a (5xx) failure at the server side, two bugs will be created - One from the frontend SDK (That has the end user activities and logs) and another from the backend SDK.

Using `djatyReqId`, Djaty knows that those bugs are related to each other and - At the dashboard - will show the Ajax timeline item with a "Backend Timeline" tab to help you debug what was happening at the server side during this Ajax was sent.